# Animals with very high bite pressures

Tags: zoology

When media, such as [this site](https://www.thoughtco.com/strongest-bites-in-the-animal-kingdom-4099136) wants to explain just how dangerous large animals are, they often quote bite-forces as pounds per square inch (psi).

However, it appears that they mixed up the units, as the numbers they give are the total force in pounds.

But what animals have the strongest bite force *per unit area*? There is no obvious scaling law here: scale up an animal 2 fold and the cross-sections of both the muscles and the teeth and jaws both quadruple. This puts tiny insect mandibles are on a level playing field with our largest beasts.

Instead, bite-pressure will be niche-dependent as well as the details of the animal's anatomy (such as mechanics of the jaws). It may be somewhat hard to define contact area given the complex shape of teeth and mouthparts in general; maybe one could measure the indented area in a tough material that the animal chomps down on.

Given that our strongest biomaterial found yet is [microscopic teeth](https://io9.gizmodo.com/sea-snail-teeth-are-the-strongest-known-biological-stru-1686509138) and that microscopic materials [tend to be stronger](https://diamondage.org/2019/12/25/fibers_fiber_strong/) than bulk materials, it seems likely to be a small animal. Is there any data to support this?

Comment: I think the correlation between strength of materials and highest bite pressure may be misguided. You don't need an even stronger exotic material or construction if maximum bite pressures can be supported by the more mundane materials and constructions that everything else with lower bite forces already uses. Kind of like assuming strength of materials in eating utencils correlates with the weight of  food being eaten...steel is already so strong food weight is not even part of the equation.

Comment: They are not confusing total force and PSI they are giving you the force per unit area. (although the megalodon is achieved with poor methods) A T-rex is putting 10,000 pounds of pressure on a square inch of tooth surface. Muscle strength is based on cross section, larger muscles have larger cross sections producing drastically more force.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Material strength is important well beyond maximum bite pressure. Accidental ingestion of rocks or bone, eccentric loading, fatigue, etc mean you want a high "safety margin". Human teeth do break after all.

Comment: @John: Don't larger mouths have larger teeth as well, so there is more tooth area to distribute the force on?

Comment: @KevinKostlan no more tooth area means a larger total force for the calculations given. Keep in mind we are given the PSI. If you were calculating from the total force then yes more area would mean less PSI. Teeth in general is a way to increase the PSI of a bite, pointed teeth spread force across a smaller area.